# Web Service connect IOS to oracle Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, web-services

I am working on an IOS application that uses oracle database. I have already done most of the work in swift. The only thing remaining is the login function and the data that needs to be stored in database. Database is already built, I just have to develop the web service for this. I don't know where to start and what is the best way to develop the web service?

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO isn't a code-writing service. You need to try yourself. If you encounter problems see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on how to write the question.

Comment: You can try Laravel or Ruby on Rails